# Proving $g(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-\omega}\, dz$ where $g$ is the inverse of $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have the following exercise:

> Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f$ be a one to one
>   function in $H(G)$ such that $f'(z)\neq0$ for all $z\in G$.
>
> For each $\omega\in f(G)$ let $g(\omega)$ denote the unique complex
>   number $z\in G$ for which $f(z)=\omega$.
>
> Suppose that the closed disk $\overline{D(z_{o},r)}\subseteq G$ and
>   that $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to G$ is the curve given by
>   $\gamma(t)=z_{0}+re^{it}$.
>
> Prove, with the help of the residue theorem, that, for every
>   $\omega\in f(D(z_{0},r))$ $$g(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi
>  i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-\omega}\, dz$$
>
> Your solution should also explain why this integral is well defined.

I will divide my question into two parts:

1. I have a solution for the case that $g(\omega)\neq0$, but there
   is an argument made in it that I can't totally justify:

> Consider the function  $$ \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-\omega} $$
>
> it have the singular point when  $$ f(z)=\omega $$
>
> since $f$ is $1-1$ and $\omega$ is in the image of $f$, there exist a
>   unique point $z_{1}$ s.t  $$ f(z_{1})=\omega $$
>
> Since $f'(z)\neq0$ we have it that  $$ h(z):=f(z)-\omega $$
>
> have a zero of order $1$. assume $z_{1}$ maps to $\omega$
>
> $z_{1}f'(z_{1})\neq0$ and $f(z_{1})-\omega=0$, $(f-\omega)'=f'\neq0$
>   hence  $$ Res\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-\omega} $$
>
> at $z=z_{1}$ is  $$ \frac{z_{1}f'(z_{1})}{(f(z)-\omega)'_{z_{1}}}=z_{1}
>  $$
>
> and by the residue theorem  $$ \frac{1}{2\pi
>  i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-\omega}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}2\pi
>  iz_{1}=z_{1}=g(\omega) $$

The part that I can't justify is why $h$ have a zero of order $1$
? I think its because $f$ is $1-1$, but I'm not sure how to use
it

2) I don't think it holds for when $g(\omega)=0$, since then $$z_{1}f'(z_{1})=0\cdot f'(0)=0$$
and so I can't use the theorem I used.

Can someone please help me with this case ?

**Added later:**

I am referring to the following theorem, that can be found at page
$253$ of the book Complex Variables and Applications by Brown and
Churchill:

> Let two functions $p,q$ be holomorphic at a point $z_{0}$. If
>   $p(z_{0})\neq0,q(z_{0})=0$ and $q'(z_{0})\neq0$ then
>   $$Res_{z=z_{0}}\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\frac{p(z_{0})}{q'(z_{0})}$$

Comment: Why do you think $z_{1}f'(z_{1})=0\cdot f'(0)=0$ prevents your argument from working? One thing you can do to see it works anyway is by expressing the numerator and denominator as power series near $z_1$, then factoring out $f'(z_1)(z - z_1)$ out of the denominator, so as to factor out $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{f'(z_1)(z - z_1)}$ out of the entire expression. The resulting *fraction* of power series is analytic at $z_0$, so has its own Taylor series there. What is the Laurent series you get when you reincorporate $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{f'(z_1)(z - z_1)}$ back in?

Comment: @bryanj - please see my edit. I am not sure that I understand your idea, could you give some more explicit details please ?

Comment: I guess what I was getting at is that if $z_1 = 0$, so that $p(z_0) = 0$ (in Churchill's Theorem), but all the other hypotheses are satisfied, then $ \displaystyle \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ *does not* have a singularity at $z_0$, so the residue is zero and you still get back $0 = z_1 = g(w)$ when you integrate.

Comment: @bryanj - I think you are right, you might want to post an answer so I can accept. I have to treat this as a special case though, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About 1: notice that if a function $f(z)$ has a zero of order $n>1$ then, $f'(z)=0$, which is excluded in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If $F(z) = \displaystyle \frac{A(z)}{B(z)}$ where $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ are analytic, and $B(z)$ has a simple zero at $z = z_1$ (so $B'(z_1) \ne 0$), then the quoted Churchill-Brown's theorem says:

$$Res( F(z); \text{ }z = z_1) = \displaystyle \frac{A(z_1)}{B'(z_1)}$$

This holds *even when* $A(z_1) = 0$.   In the case when $A(z_1) = 0$, then the function $F(z)$ is either analytic at $z = z_0$ or has a removable discontinuity there. In this case, $Res( F(z) ; \text{ }z = z_1) = 0$.

Either way you get the result that you want: $Res( F(z) ; \text{ }z = z_1) = g(w)$.

A good way to see why $Res( F(z); \text{ }z = z_1) = \displaystyle \frac{A(z_1)}{B'(z_1)}$
is true (as long as $B'(z_1) \ne 0$) near an isolated simple pole or *removable* singularity is to write out $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ as power series near the singularity, and factor out $(z - z_1)$ out of the denominator power series and see what's left over.

The Bak/Newman book *Complex Analysis* has a great exposition of Laurent and Power series, and residues.